# grep lines having "CC" but not more C

Tags: grep

For example, I have the lines:

```
CCP2007
CCCP
CCCCPPPPCCC
CCCCCPPPPPCCCCC
```

I want to show the first one, the `CCP2007`, because there are only two letters `C` in the row.
What's the command for it?

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  On the lines you want to match, are the two `C`s always next to each other (always `CC`) or can they be separated (eg. `CPPC`)?

Comment: What aboout `CCPCC` or `CCPCCC`? Or do you only want to print lines containing a single `CC` with no other `C`s anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Match lines starting with `CC` having no other occurence of the character `C` in the line:

```
grep '^CC[^C]*$' file
```

Same thing, without demanding `CC` to be at the beginning of the line:

```
grep '^[^C]*CC[^C]*$' file
```

---

And without considering the total count of `C` characters in the line:

Match lines starting with `CC` but not with `CCC` (e.g. `CCAC` is matching, `CCCA` is discarded):

```
grep '^CC[^C]' file
```

Match lines with maximum and minimum 2 repetitive `C` anywhere:

```
grep -v 'CCC'| grep 'CC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep's PCRE mode with perl-style *lookarounds* to match `CC` where it is neither preceded by nor followed by `C`:

```
grep -P '(?<!C)CC(?!C)'
```

or faking something similar with ERE mode:

```
grep -E '(^|[^C])CC([^C]|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find lines containing exactly  characters from the class :

```
grep '^[^]*\([][^]*\)\{\}$'
```

the specific case here has ={C} and =2:

```
grep '^[^C]*\([C][^C]*\)\{2\}$'
```

and the brackets can be removed from the single-character class, for a final answer of:

```
grep '^[^C]*\(C[^C]*\)\{2\}$'
```